# I have difficulty in deriving children from a Promise

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There are list. I need to find `Item 3` element and click on the '2' button in this element. What can I do it?

html:

```
<body>
  <div class="list>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
       <p> Item 1 </p>
      </div>
      <button class='btn'> 1 </button>
      <button class='btn'> 2 </button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
       <p> Item 2 </p>
      </div>
      <button class='btn'> 1 </button>
      <button class='btn'> 2 </button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
       <p> Item 3 </p>
      </div>
      <button class='btn'> 1 </button>
      <button class='btn'> 2 </button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
       <p> Item 4 </p>
      </div>
      <button class='btn'> 1 </button>
      <button class='btn'> 2 </button>
    </div>     
  </div>
</body>
```

js:

```
let findButtons = await 
    driver.findElements(By.className('item'));

    let buttons = findButtons.map(elem => elem.getText());
    const allButtons = await Promise.all(buttons);

    //    ***   Find button  ***
    let tButton;
    for (let i = 0; i < findButtons.length; i++) {
      if (allButtons[i] == `Item 3`) {   // compare all elements. Find `Item 3` element
        tButton = await findButtons[i];
        console.log(tButton.children);   // need to display list of the children elements, 
  but it is displayed - underfined

             tButton.click();                 // click on the element is available
        // but I need to click on the '2' button in the `Item 3` element
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get element using `xpath`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='item' and contains(.,'Item 2')]//button[normalize-space(.)='2']")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following `xpath`:

```
//div[@class='item' and contains(.,'Item 3')]//button[2]
```

Or:

```
//p[contains(text(),'Item 3')]//parent::div//following-sibling::button[2]
```

`button[2]` - refers to the second button.

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div//p[contains(.,'Item 3')]/parent::div/following-sibling::button[2]")
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following `Xpath`.

```
//div[@class='item'][.//p[normalize-space(.)='Item 3']]//button[2]
```